# Is it always true that an element has the same order as its inverse?

Tags: group-theory

If I have a group $G$ and I take two subgroups $\langle g\rangle$ and $\langle g^{-1}\rangle $. Are their orders equal?

So far, I am just trying to find counterexamples. I worked with dihedral groups, integer modulos, etc. but all of them seemed to work well and the orders seem to be same.

How do I prove this for general case if it is true?

Comment: "...and..."?${}{}{}{}{}$ You ask about orders in the title, but then you talk about equal subgroups...Which one is it?

Comment: I meant the order of <g> is equal to order of <g^-1>

Comment: The order of <g> is the order of g, by definition.

Comment: Then why do you ask about subgroups? And yes: the order of $\;g\;$ equals that of $\;g^{-1}\;$ . Try to prove it yourself, it isn't hard.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think the op does not aware to the notion of little oh and big oh, for him $o$ is for order, so he asks whether the order of $g$ is equal tot he order of $g^{-1}$

Comment: @ArnaudMortier No, it isn't. Those are, at least by definition, different concepts, although it's rather easy to show that the two numbers coincide. The order of $g$ is the smallest positive power of $g$ which gives the identity element. The order of $\langle g\rangle$ is the cardinality of the set $\{\ldots,g^{-1}, e, g, g^2,\ldots\}$.

Comment: @yanko Tha's exactly what I addressed and answered. I didn't mean *at all* little "o"...in fact, I couldn't tell what is little "o" within general group theory...

Comment: @Arthur you're right. By definition here meant "by definition and easy arguments".